# How to return an answer from Yes/No answer out of respective function?

Tags: python

I am asking a Yes or No prompt to a user as a function and I want to return what the answer was back to the rest of the code.

How could I get the answer from the yesNo() function to figure out if the user would like to run the intro variable/function?

```
prompt = " >>> "


def yesNo():
    answer = input('(Y/N)' + prompt)
    i = 1
    while i > 0:
        if answer == str.lower("y"):
            tutorial()
            i = 0
        elif answer == str.lower('n'):
            startGame()
            i = 0
        else:
            print("command not understood. try again.")


def newGame():
    print("would you like a tutorial?")
    yesNo()
```

Comment: sorry , can you elaborate better "How could I get the answer from the yesNo() function to figure out if the user would like to run the intro variable/function? Many thanks." ?

Comment: Pardon my vagueness, I want to use the answer from yesNo() to trigger another function but I am unsure of how to get the input from yesNo back up to trigger something outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want something closer to this:

```
def get_user_input(choices):
    prompt = "Please enter ({}): ".format("/".join(f"'{choice}'" for choice in choices))
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt)
        if user_input in choices:
            break
        prompt = "Unsupported command '{}', Try again: ".format(user_input)
    return user_input


def main():
    print("Would you like a tutorial?")
    user_input = get_user_input(["Yes", "No"])

    if user_input == "Yes":
        tutorial()
    startGame()
```

The function that gets user input should only be responsible for getting user input, and returning the user's provided input to the calling code. It should not have any other side-effects, like starting a tutorial, or starting the game.

Answer (score 0):

To get the answer of the user outside the `yesNo()` method, you can use `return`, and then store the returned value in a variable

Like this:

```
prompt = " >>> "


def yesNo():
    
    i = 1
    while i > 0:
        answer = input('(Y/N)' + prompt)
        if answer == str.lower("y"):
            tutorial()
            i = 0
        elif answer == str.lower('n'):
            startGame()
            i = 0
        else:
            print("command not understood. try again.")

        return answer


def newGame():
    print("would you like a tutorial?")
    answer = yesNo()
```